# Null reference used for synchronization

Tags: java, android, crash

When I leave my Android app running for about 30 minutes, it sometimes crashes. I then open the system logs and find where this crash happens (I cannot debug this app any other way due to special circumstances). Usually, when there is a glaring error in my code, this log contains a stack trace. This specific crash, however, does not leave a stack trace at all. It does, however, leave the following information:

```
06-19 14:13:08.738  2216 18026 F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 18026 (Thread-1214), pid 2216 (s.flironecamera)
06-19 14:13:08.739  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: values = 50.0
06-19 14:13:08.739  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: onReceive lux: 50.0  action: 
06-19 14:13:08.740  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: Inject brightness form Cam 50.0
06-19 14:13:08.740  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: Inject calibrated lux
06-19 14:13:08.741  4169  4169 I Sensors : AutoBrightnessSensor::inject_sensor_data: cam_lux 50
06-19 14:13:08.854 18054 18054 E crash_dump64: unknown process state: t
06-19 14:13:08.916 18054 18054 I crash_dump64: obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
06-19 14:13:08.926  4292  4292 I /system/bin/tombstoned: received crash request for pid 18026
06-19 14:13:08.929 18054 18054 I crash_dump64: performing dump of process 2216 (target tid = 18026)
06-19 14:13:08.941  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: values = 50.0
06-19 14:13:08.942  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: onReceive lux: 50.0  action: 
06-19 14:13:08.942  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: Inject brightness form Cam 50.0
06-19 14:13:08.942  4697 16938 D MotionRecognitionService: Inject calibrated lux
06-19 14:13:08.945  4169  4431 I Sensors : AutoBrightnessSensor::inject_sensor_data: cam_lux 50
06-19 14:13:08.947 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-19 14:13:08.947 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: [redacted]
06-19 14:13:08.947 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : Revision: '10'
06-19 14:13:08.948 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : Timestamp: 2020-06-19 14:13:08-0300
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : pid: 2216, tid: 18026, name: Thread-1214  >>> com.samples.flironecamera <<<
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : uid: 10269
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::JavaException: java.lang.NullPointerException Null reference used for synchronization (monitor-enter)'
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000000000000000  x1  000000000000466a  x2  0000000000000006  x3  0000007e3b2d4380
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x4  feff287164736d64  x5  feff287164736d64  x6  feff287164736d64  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x8  00000000000000f0  x9  5e1c42c9d736fe8b  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x12 fffffff0fffffbdf  x13 28206e6f6974617a  x14 0000000000000004  x15 0000007ed145d412
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000007ed14638c0  x17 0000007ed1440920  x18 00000000000036b4  x19 00000000000008a8
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x20 000000000000466a  x21 00000000ffffffff  x22 ffffff80ffffffc8  x23 0000007e3b2d45d0
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000007e3b2d44b0  x25 0000007e3b2d44f0  x26 000000000000001e  x27 0000007de0eeeb80
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000007de0eeeb98  x29 0000007e3b2d4420
06-19 14:13:08.949 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007e3b2d4360  lr  0000007ed13f5108  pc  0000007ed13f5134
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : 
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #00 pc 0000000000083134  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+160) (BuildId: ecce0f8f6d05a6808531d834fd5e2b07)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #01 pc 00000000000a48c8  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (offset 0x1bb000) (BuildId: b062ae10a54d94f888c84c4f3bba0a8b30363bd7)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #02 pc 00000000000a4ac8  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (offset 0x1bb000) (BuildId: b062ae10a54d94f888c84c4f3bba0a8b30363bd7)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #03 pc 00000000000b92b8  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (offset 0x1bb000) (BuildId: b062ae10a54d94f888c84c4f3bba0a8b30363bd7)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #04 pc 00000000000b899c  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (offset 0x1bb000) (BuildId: b062ae10a54d94f888c84c4f3bba0a8b30363bd7)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #05 pc 00000000000b891c  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libc++_shared.so (offset 0x1bb000) (__cxa_throw+120) (BuildId: b062ae10a54d94f888c84c4f3bba0a8b30363bd7)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #06 pc 0000000000487638  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (atlasCheckException(_JNIEnv*)+216) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #07 pc 00000000004c717c  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (_Z10callMethodIvJEEN14wrapped_resultIT_E4typeEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectPKcDpOT0_+88) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.962 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #08 pc 00000000004cc7b8  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (jni::live::JavaConnector::startFrameStream(bool)+136) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.963 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #09 pc 0000000000931d1c  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (RBPDeviceWrapper::TransportCommunicatorImplementation::dispatchFrameStreamControlRequestToDelegates(bool) const+232) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.963 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #10 pc 000000000093d374  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (RBPDeviceWrapper::DeviceImplementation::handleFrameCaptureRequest(RBPDeviceWrapper::DeviceImplementation*, zmq::message_t const&, bool)+128) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.963 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #11 pc 0000000000957d80  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (RBPDeviceWrapper::ZMQSocketEventLoop<RBPDeviceWrapper::DeviceImplementation>::loopThreadBody(void*)+348) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.963 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #12 pc 0000000000959c08  /data/app/com.samples.flironecamera-Ja8FY8rW-sZLXm5PKmpvqQ==/base.apk!libatlas_native.so (offset 0x7cf000) (_ZNSt6__ndk114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEPFPvS7_EPN16RBPDeviceWrapper18ZMQSocketEventLoopINSA_20DeviceImplementationEEEEEEEES7_S7_+44) (BuildId: 70c0a8d0e08f60afb8dccd5e563b484d106e30a6)
06-19 14:13:08.963 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #13 pc 00000000000e28c0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36) (BuildId: ecce0f8f6d05a6808531d834fd5e2b07)
06-19 14:13:08.963 18054 18054 F DEBUG   :       #14 pc 000000000008503c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64) (BuildId: ecce0f8f6d05a6808531d834fd5e2b07)
```

My app's name is com.samples.flironecamera (this was a temporary name, it was built off of a sample project), and it utilises the Flir SDK. Is there a way to tell what the specific cause of the crash was? Is it possible that this crash is caused by the SDK itself and is not my code's fault?

I am not posting my code here because there is about 10000 lines of it and I don't know which parts are relevant. If the error dump points towards the usage of a certain method, please leave a comment and I will gladly post the section of my code that uses anything relevant to it. If it helps, **I do not use assert statements or synchronization anywhere in any of my code**.

Comment: ever figure this out?  My FLIR app crashes the same way!

Comment: @confused unfortunately I never managed to fix this crash. Luckily for me my app is more of a service so I could just relaunch it whenever it crashed (using a dead-man's-trigger mechanism). I did end up tracing this crash to the FLIR SDK itself. The SDK has been updated since this question was asked and the developers may have fixed this crash, but the updated version is even more buggy than the previous version so I actually reverted back.

Comment: @confused I managed to make this crash less frequent by doing a few things: Make any methods that deal with a camera-related object synchronized, make any camera-related objects volatile, and use a linked blocking queue of runnables to handle any operations on the camera with a delay between each run command (this way, you can ensure any camera operations are handled one at a time with enough time for the camera to "recover", for lack of a better word, in between the operations). These methods are sketchy but they've helped